# Tor over VPN - http status code 404 not found

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, directory, error

```
[warn] Received http status code 404 ("Not found") from server 'x.x.x.x:9001' while fetching "/tor/keys/fp/(40-key-characters and numbers)".
```

Is there a way to allow the keys?
Is it important to have the keys for that session?

Answer (score 2):

The error means you got a 404 - not found while asking a directory cache for the key certificate for the authority identified by the fingerprint <40-key-characters and numbers>. The address x.x.x.x is the cache itself.

Tor will try another for you.

-- leeroy